# Dapper SqlConnection becomes null or closed after ExecuteAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dapper, sqlconnection

I am using Dapper in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application. I used DI to inject `SqlConnection` and begin a transaction, as shown below. Then in one of my services, I use the UnitOfWork to make to inserts into two different tables.

The first insert is OK but for the second one both of my `_sqlConnection` and `_dbTransaction` variables become null. I have no idea how this is happening. Could you help, please.

`Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped((s) => new SqlConnection(Configuration["APPSETTINGS_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING"]));

services.AddScoped<IDbTransaction>((s) =>
            {
                var connection = s.GetRequiredService<SqlConnection>();
                var tokenService = s.GetRequiredService<ITokenService>();
                connection.AccessToken = tokenService.GetAccessToken();
                connection.Open();
                return connection.BeginTransaction();
            });
services.AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>();
services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

`RepositoryBase.cs`:

```
public RepositoryBase(IDbTransaction dbTransaction, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
    _dbTransaction = dbTransaction;
    _sqlConnection = sqlConnection;         
}
    
private async Task<int> CreateEntity(T entity, string sql)
{
    return await _sqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(sql, transaction: _dbTransaction);
}
```

`Service.cs`:

```
var workerMappingTask = _unitOfWork.MappingRepository.CreateAsync(
                        WorkerMappingEntity.Create(1,"test","12"));
    
var workerConsentTask = _unitOfWork.WorkerRepository.CreateAsync(100,"test","123","123"));
    
await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { workerMappingTask, workerConsentTask });

_unitOfWork.Commit();
```

Comment: [Captive dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines?source=recommendations#captive-dependency)

Comment: I don't know, but you can't execute two commands on the same connection simultaneously